# callbacks of "org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage"

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I have a WizardPage is displayed by org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard through [Next] and [Back] buttons. I would like some operations will be always executed once this WizardPage is displayed and disappeared.
I check all the methods defined in WizardPage but I do not find anything like "OnEnter()" or "OnLeave()". Does WizardPage provide this mechanism?
If not, does that imply I have to implement this mechanism in org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard? If so, what might be a good entry point to implement this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `WizardPage` `setVisible` method to do something when the page is made visible or invisible:

```
@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible)
{
  super.setVisible(visible);   // You should always call the super method

  // TODO your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method `setVisible(`... this is defined in the interface `IDialogPage` that is implemented in the `WizardPage`

Example:

```
@Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {

        if (visible) {
            // the code when your page is getting displayed
        } else {
            // the code when your page is getting hide
        }
        super.setVisible(visible);

    };
```